# Drupal full html vs filtered html

Tags: html, drupal

What exactly is the difference between full html and filtered html? I have heard that filtered html is safer to use but that you can't add images without changing a few settings. What are the advantages of filtered html vs full html? Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's text filtering is highly configurable. By default there are three filters (Drupal 7). Plain Text,Full HTML and Filtered HTML.

Contrib modules provide additional filtering capabilities e.g. the Twitter module allows you to convert all @username links to a valid link to Twitter etc.

A closer look at the formats will have you discover that they are mostly the 'same'. Case in point; the Filtered HTML differs from Full HTML by the fact that it limits the types of HTML tags that can be used. Technically this implies that Filtered HTML can easily be made Full HTML depending on what you enable/disable.

For ease of classification and better grained control they are named differently and carry different capabilities.You can always roll out your own. After all this is Drupal...the 'al' must be short for alternatives:-)